# Not sure on class design

Tags: c#, user-interface

i originally had a main form with 2 panels, one had a graph in that i clicked on the other had the results displayed related to what you clicked.

All this code was dumped in the main form.

I tried to be a smart alec and use inheritance, so now i have a main form which has a graph objet and i have a superclass graph -> subclass specific graph heirarchy

however now when the graph is displayed in the main form, how do i get the data back to display in the other panel? The reason i ask this is now that the graph stuff is in its own heirarchy, it has no knowledge of the panel on the main form so i have no hwere to set the data when it is set

i hope someone can help

thanks

edit: i think i might just pass the control collection for the panel in to my graph class so i can add the relevant items in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the relation between the two forms, you can use events to message data between them.

A click event handeled in the graph can raise an event with the data you need to display, which would end up on the owning form. Depending on the relationship, you either call a function on the 2nd form to display the data, or raise an event to which the 2nd form subscribed to send over the data.

[Edit]

I read Forms instead of Panels.

The main idea remains the same though. From your style of writing, it looks like you have an Objective C history. I know on the Mac, these things would be done in Interface Builder, setting bindings to make this stuff happen, but in the .NET Winforms you do these things in code (handeling events, calling methods, etc). If you like to stick more to the way it's done with Interface Builder, you might want to take a look at WPF applications; bindings work in a very similar way to how it's done on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I would design this as an object that aggregates another object.  Have a look at the way master-detail view works.